# Is it possible to retrieve the headers sent by a proxy when said proxy is used for HTTPS with HTTPClient?

Tags: c#, https, proxy, httpclient

My situation is the following :

I have a client A *(HttpClient/HttpClientHandler)* that wants to post some stuff on an HTTPS page C.

But to do so it uses a proxy B (HTTP Proxy).

B adds some custom headers to the first response to A, before the tunneling to C.

So when A sends:

```
CONNECT randomwebsite.com:443 HTTP/1.1
Host: randomwebsite.com:443
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
```

B sends back:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
X-Custom-Header: my value
```

then starts tunneling the HTTPS traffic.

Is there anyway in .Net to retrieve this header, or the handshake with the proxy is completely lost?